# How to monitor .net 7 metrics inside VS 2022?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, metrics, .net-7.0, open-telemetry

I implemented a simple metrics counter from this blog: https://www.meziantou.net/monitoring-a-dotnet-application-using-opentelemetry.htm#metrics

If I run the app from command line as a standalone app I can see the counter changing values:

```
dotnet counters monitor --process-id 123 --counters MyApplication
```

However if I run it from VS the monitor doesnt see the app - it sits with "Waiting for initial payload..." message.

How can I monitor metrics while running app from VS 2022?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new VS 2022 v 17.8 now let's you monitor metrics in the diagnostics window

Answer (score 1):

When running from Visual Studio 2022, you won't use the CLI `dotnet counters` tool. Instead you'll want to attach the profiler from within VS2022.

To do this:

1. Open the "Debug" menu
2. Select "Performance Profiler..."
3. Check the box next to ".NET Counters"
4. Click "Start"

[See the Visual Studio 2022 documentation for more details on the profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/dotnet-counters-tool?view=vs-2022)

Comment: good answer. however I dont see the counter I added programmatically. and thats the whole point of this question